# why can not I change the permission and ownership of files in mount hard disk?

Tags: server, mount, permissions

I mount a hard disk in ubuntu server with

```
sudo mkdir /hard
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /hard
```

then I find that the permission is `777`, and the mounted files are also `777`, so I want to change the permission of them, I tried this:

```
chmod 755 /hard/ -R
```

I find that all files' permission remains `777`. Here is the permission:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root          0 May 11 22:48 d5d3eda62d1fc7f8925be8e39153d3bd/
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root          0 Apr  4 15:42 movie/
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root          0 May 11 20:47 music/
```

I also tried to change owner of these files, I also failed.

```
chown -R roger:roger /hard
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because NTFS is a Windows filesystem and it does NOT use Linux permissions.

You set the permissions for NTFS during mounting.

To set permissions on a ntfs partition use uid, gid, umask during mounting. See the NTFS section in `man mount`.

Comment: `man mount` is probably not directly useful here, since it doesn't have an `ntfs-3g` section.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, NTFS is a Windows filesystem, which doesn't quite map directly to the [traditional unix permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions). An artificial mapping is done by default (see [`ntfs-3g` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html) , *Access Handling and Security*):

> By default, files and directories are owned by the effective  user  and
>          group  of  the  mounting  process,  and everybody has full read, write,
>          execution and directory browsing  permissions.   You  can  also  assign
>          permissions  to  a  single user by using the uid and/or the gid options
>          together with the umask, or fmask and dmask options.

(This is quite similar to the way FAT filesystems are mounted too.)

There is fundamentally a problem of mapping Linux users to Windows users, which has direct consequences on the permission model (see [*User Mapping* section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html#contenttoc4) of that man page). You also can use a more advanced configuration there (see `permissions` and `acl` options), but this will involve a finer grained access control model, closer to [what you can do on Ext filesystems with ACLs enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs), which will not be visible by only looking at the traditional `rwxrwxrwx` model.

(Note that the NTFS section in `man mount` doesn't apply to `ntfs-3g`, which you're using.)